# Связь один-ко-многим: как задать первичный ключ?

Tags: key, linq, sql

Ситуация следующая:
Есть Список Отделов и список работников. У каждого отдела свой уникальный номер, например (125, 160, 175 и т.д.). У работника, соответственно, также есть свой айди (1001, 1002, 1003 и т.д.).

Так вот, мне нужна связь один-ко-многим (в одном отделе работают несколько работников).
Я пытаюсь изменить значение первичного ключа, но не выходит. Все остальные я могу менять. В итоге получается, что я не могу набить данными таблицу Отделов, чтобы спокойно прописать значения Foreign Keys. : ) Меня не устраивают значения, идущие подряд типа 1, 2, 3 и т.д., по возрастанию.

Другими словами, непонятно, как динамически задавать значения первичного ключа Ид Отдела только те, которые мне нужны.

Comment: Во-первых, менять занчение первичного ключа - плохая идея. 

Чтобы сделать связь один-ко-многим, в таблице работников создайте поле, которое будет хранить ID отдела и свяжите это поле и таблицу отделов внешним ключом

Comment: > Меня не устраивают значения, идущие подряд типо 1, 2, 3 и т.д., по возрастанию.

1. идущие подряд**,** тип**а**
2. чем не устраивают?

Comment: Не используйте счетчик (IDENTITY) для ключа.

Comment: Да, действительно, в одних примерах IDENTITY у PK нет, а в других - есть, но почему-то запрещено изменять первичный ключ в редакторе .MDF базы данных в Visual Studio. Неужели при INSERT-е он айдишник сам вставит?   
  Да, кстати, в том примере, где нет IDENTITY, там вместо чисел слова используются. Понятно теперь, зачем )) - слова-то хрен проинкрементишь.

Comment: Разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

Уберите Identity у ID.

1. Создайте отделы с ID 125,160 вручную. (Учтите, что вам нужно самим разобраться с дублированием, т.к. оно в этом случае недопустимо)
2. У пользователей можете добавить внешний ключ, который будет ссылаться на ID Отдела.
3. При добавлении работника с его ID 1001, записывайте в поле ОтделID 125 соответсвтено.